# Using IoC (Castle Windsor) with dependencies determined at request time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor

I have an existing MVC app where I use Castle Windsor as IoC container. It runs in Azure as a Web App.

We have recently expanded the functionality with a new controller based on ASP.Net Web API.

The container is set up and configured in global.asax

But - due to the different nature of the MVC framework and the Web API framework, specifically how they handle `HttpContext`, we have some code at the core part of our code, that needs to work according to which controller method was executed. The code for doing this is seperated in two different classes (implementing the same interface).

The solution we have now is to configure the container with both instances, inject both instances to the class, and at runtime figure out (by investigating the `HttpContext` data) which to execute code on.

But I think that sucks.

Is there any way we can do this better? Can we instruct Castle Windsor to figure out which instance to inject at runtime - based on e.g. a value in the URI?

Comment: An `IHandlerSelector` might do the job. A very similar scenario is discussed here: http://www.longest.io/2015/03/13/select-between-components-castle-windsor.html